# Polymorphism in c++ with templated classes

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I would like to use a templated class in c++ with one of the template argument determined by user input in run-time. I am pretty sure there is an easy and nice way to do it but I am quite new to c++ and I am still struggling with polymorphism and template classes...

Here is what I would like to do:

```
if (argument==0)
      typedef Class1 ActualClassUsed;
if (argument==1)
      typedef Class2 ActualClassUsed;

MyTemplatedClass<ActualClassUsed> * object= MyTemplatedClass<ActualClassUsed>::New();
```

obviously in the example above ActualClassUsed is not defined in the proper scope... Any easy way to correct this ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: _"with one of the template argument determined by user input in run-time."_ That's not possible. Templates are instantiated at compile time.

Comment: What about Factory pattern and common parent class (common interface)

Comment: @skypjack But the attempt shown how to do that is completely wrong. You need the template instances beforehand already, and select which should be used to create an object instance at runtime. Factory pattern as mentioned in the comment above is probably the right way to go.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I was joking. ;-)

Comment: ok thx for your answers, I guess I will look at factory patterns!

Answer (score 0):

Templates is actually duplicating the same code with corresponding data(*needed data types only ,not all*) types.That is actually happens at compile time.

Templates is useful when different data type's (either user defined or built in data types) process in the same way

currently it is not possible to instantiate template at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to use a templated class in c++ with one of the template argument determined by user input in run-time. I am pretty sure there is an easy and nice way to do it

Nope there isn't.
It's actually fundamentally impossible by design.

Templates are a developer tool which generates code the moment you compile your program, which hopefully happens ***before*** it is run by any user, time travel aside it is pretty hard to use an information before someone gave it to you.

You can't decide on a fixed color for the car you're building in your factory based on which day the futur driver is going to use it. If you want something like that it has to be a dynamic chameleon like color which changes based on the day.